# IndexError: list index out of range - despite that index seems within range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning programming on my own. I am working on the following codingbat problem:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.

```
def sum67(nums):
    sum = 0
    pos6 = []
    pos7 = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 6:
            pos6 = pos6 + [i]
    for i in range(pos6[0],len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 7:
            pos7 = pos7 + [i]
    pos7 = pos7[:len(pos6)]
    start_pos = pos6[0]
    end_pos = pos7[-1]
    for i in range(start_pos,end_pos+1):
        nums[i] = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sum = sum + nums[i]
    return sum
sum67([2,3,5])
sum67([6,8,3,7,5,9])
sum67([6,7,9,2,1])
sum67([6,7,6,7,7])
sum67([6,7])
sum67([7,8])
```

I get the following error when I run the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/q1/Google Drive/Python - Practice Examples/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    sum67([2,3,5])
  File "C:/Users/q1/Google Drive/Python - Practice Examples/test.py", line 10, in sum67
    for i in range(pos6[0],len(nums)):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I execute the program, python shows me the error: "IndexError: list index out of range". I know what this error means but unable to understand why is it showing that in my case?

Comment: Well, since none of the elements in the input list are 6, `pos6` remains an empty list, so it has no first element. What were you expecting? (Also, I think you can greatly simplify this, such that it iterates through the list only once.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is because pos6 will have values if list consists of 6 i.e. it is actually inside if nums[i] == 6:. you should run your next for loop inside this if statement because pos6 will only have value if 6 exists in list like so:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 6:
        pos6 = pos6 + [i]
        for i in range(pos6[0],len(nums)):
```

Hope it helps.